# prepareForSegue never got called even though I set the segue in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

Im new to iOS development, Im trying to follow the course in Udacity.

But having trouble in performing the segue.

the `prepareForSegue` never got called in my second viewcontroller.

I have two viewcontroller, one is **ViewController**, the other is **PlaySoundViewController**.

[image]

and I have link those from story board to the real class in swift.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

and I have drag from the first view controller to second one to generate a segue and named it as "gonext".

[image]

and I called `performSegueWithIdentifier("gonext", sender:aduio);`

and in the second view controller I implement the `prepareForSegue`, however, it never got called.... but it managed to go to the next view.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go to the next view controller you have to perform the method

```
Self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gonext", sender:aduio);
```

The one thing that you are getting wrong is that you have to run the prepareForSegue method in the first view controller and not the second view controller to send the data.

So instead of running the prepareForSegue method in the second view controller just run it in the first.

Comment: The `self` is implied.  You don't need to state it explicitly, but it you do it should be lowercase.  But, yes, his `prepareForSegue` should be in the first view controller.

Comment: thanks, Both of you, Im a little messed up with the Android concept in handling the data from views to views....